# PHP Pagination with WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<div>    
<form method="post" action="admission_list_fetch5.php">
Enter Cousre Code: <input name="course_code" placeholder="course code">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
<div>
     <table border="2" id="enquirytable" style= "border-collapse:collapse;"">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:50;">SL No</th>
          <th>Student ID</th>
          <th>Enrol No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Course</th>
          <th>Semester</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

<?php 
//error_reporting(0);
$num_rec_per_page=10;
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('nobledatabase');
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
$course_code=$_POST['course_code'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM admission_list where course_code='$course_code' LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); //run the query

        $i=1;
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs_result ) )
    {
        echo ("<tr><td  style='text-align:center'>$i</td>".
        "<td>{$row['student_id']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['enrol']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['name']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['course']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['sem_year']}</td></tr>\n");
        $i++;
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM admission_list where course_code='$course_code'";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page);
?>

</div><!--enquirytable-->

<div class="enquirypages">
<br>
<?php
echo "<a href='admission_list_fetch5.php?page=1&course_code=$course_code'>".'<<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='admission_list_fetch5.php?page=".$i."&course_code=$course_code'> ".$i." "; 
}; 
echo "<a href='admission_list_fetch5.php?page=$total_pages&course_code=$course_code'>".'>>'."</a> "; // Goto last page

?>
</div>

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Even if I pass the parameters to all the pages, I am getting the same error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: course_code in C:\wamp\www\admission_list_fetch5.php on line 33
```

Comment: Please copy the full error message to your question.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: course_code in C:\wamp\www\admission_list_fetch5.php on line 33

Comment: Are you showing the code for admission_list_fetch5.php? is it posting to itself?

Comment: (1) Notice is not the same as an error message (2) What is line 33 in your code?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using POST to get the data?

Answer (score 3):

When I look at the logic it seems that the only value that supplies the `course_code` variable comes from the `$_POST['course_code']`. This means that you have to submit from a form `post` every time to populate this variable.

The assumption is that the 2nd code peace is the `admission_list_fetch5.php`.
Whenever paging occurs then clicking on the `<a href` link passing query strings at no point does course_code get assigned using a `$_GET['course_code']`. Therefore course_code query string will always be empty.

I would suggest the following on the assumption `admission_list_fetch5.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['course_code']))
{
   $course_code = $_POST['course_code'];
}

if(isset($_GET['course_code']))
{
   $course_code = $_GET['course_code'];
}
```

Not very elegant but serves the purpose. When you post to this page there should be not query string therefore the code will default to the `$_POST['course_code']`. If a query string was set for then it will override using  `$_GET['course_code']`.

Comment: wow.. I am very greatful to you sir, thank u so much... I got the answer when i used this line       $course_code = $_GET['course_code'];

Comment: Glad it works. Please accept the answer when you get a chance.